# CORS | allow private network access to my server

Tags: cors, private-network-access

Recently chrome introduced the Private Network Access (formerly known as CORS-RFC1918) which restricts the ability of websites to send requests to servers on private networks.

I'm an owner of an internal server and I'd like to receive and respond to such requests anyway.
My server is a private HTTPS server and I have no problem receiving requests (XHR) from external HTTPS servers, I'd like to also be able to send a request from a public HTTP website to my server, how can I achieve this?

- The address of the public website is not constant, I'd like to allow all the HTTP websites such communication with my server.

Comment: Can't you simply expose your server to the public Internet? Will be much less headache.

Comment: Much less headache is true but I can't

Comment: Try sending a `Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network: true` header from your server.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network: true is the response that should be sent from the server to a preflight request of the client. There are currently no preflight requests from the client at all since google reverted the change of adding it.

Comment: By the way even before they reverted it there were no preflight requests from public HTTP to private HTTPS

Comment: Well, then you can simply use some rare non-private IP address for your private server, e.g. 1.2.3.4